# Add rotator in android

Tags: android, ads

How can I make text scroll?

I want an effect similar to ad rotators in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/). They have a library to place ads in your application. Also, google adsense offers mobile ads. AdMob was also acquired by google recently so it will eventually be part of adsense.

Answer (score 0):

AceAbhi, are you looking for autoscrolling text? or text which the user scrolls?

For auto scrolling you need to use

`android:ellipsize="marquee" android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"`

For the user to scroll the text manually you need to use

`android:scrollHorizontally="true"`